# Python send png file to default printer

Tags: python, image, png

I have a thermal printer and I would love to print a logo on top of the receipt... Is there something such as shutil.copyfile for png images?

My code is the following

```
   locations = ['/dev/usb/lp0', '/dev/usb/lp1', '/dev/usb/lp2']
        size = locations.__len__()
        i = 0

        while i < size:
            printer = locations[i]
            try:
                shutil.copyfile('output.txt', printer)
                break
            except IOError:
                i += 1

        if i == size:
            logging.error('Unable to connect to the printer')
```

Comment: `size = len(locations)`..  we use reportlab (https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab) for anything that goes to the printer, but that's a lot more complex than what you have now...

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am still trying different settings but I will definitely take a look at the one that you just mentioned.

Comment: maybe this is helpful..? https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/command-line-image-printing-in-linux.739845/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution that I was able to find thanks to thebjorn

```
os.system("lp -o fit-to-page -o orientation-requested=3 -o media=Custom.58x210mm logo.png")
```

Thank you, everyone.